# xenserver guest port 80 running apache gives default citrix xenserver page

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, xen, xenserver

I have a hp server, running xenserver 7. On xenserver I have a guest, CentOS, which is running apache webserver on port 80. That guest has the static ip 192.168.0.4, xenserver 192.168.0.3.
When I visit the CentOS (192.168.0.4) webpage with my web browser, I get the default "Welcome to Citrix XenServer" page instead of my apache website.
Sometimes I get the website running on apache after a reboot or reassigning the ethernet port to the centos vm.

The webserver is connected to a switch, which is connected to the same router as the computer I'm visiting the website with.

Could someone tell my why I'm seeing the xenserver page, or how I could find this out?

Comment: please provide a printscreen from xencenter of the management port's config. and did you changed the xenserver ip lately ?

Comment: It would also be useful to see the output of "apachectl -S" on the guest.

Comment: Thank you @yagmoth555 , I was using openxenmanager, but with xencenter I quickly saw that the serverinterface had the same ip address as the centos guest. I tought the serverinterface had the same ip as the managementinterface. Problem solved!